# kotlin access property of anonymous object

Tags: kotlin

How do I access the property `word` of the object of the anonymous object

```
 fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val sentence = "this is a nice sentence"

        val wordLengths: List<Any> = sentence.split(' ').map {
            object {
                val length = it.length
                val word = it
            }
        }

        wordLengths.forEach { it:Any -> println(it) }
    }
```

Comment: You define a class and use that class instead of using Any?

Comment: yea .. I am wondering  why they allow me to elegantly create an  `object` and then not give me a way to access property ..

Comment: Describe your problem clearly please.

Comment: What stops you from using `wordLengths.forEach { println(it.word) }`?

Comment: thats the thing. It wont compile ..

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using? It compiles and runs for me using `1.3.21`.

Comment: 1.3.1 .. If you copy paste this code to https://try.kotlinlang.org .. It wont run

Comment: Ah, I missed something—don't declare `wordsLength` to be a `List<Any>`. Just let it infer the type.

Comment: Insane !!! If you answer then I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are explicitly declaring `wordLengths` to be `List<Any>`, and `Any` doesn't have a `word` or `length` property. You should let Kotlin infer the type from `map`.

```
fun main() {
    val sentence = "This is a nice sentence"

    val wordLengths = sentence.split(' ').map {
        object {
            val word = it
            val length = it.length
        }
    }

    wordLengths.forEach {
        println("[${it.length}] ${it.word}")
    }
}
```

If you plan on needing this object outside of the method then you should create the necessary class or use an existing class (e.g. `Pair` or `String` itself). See [Object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

> Note that anonymous objects can be used as types only in local and private declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the anonymous object, or `Any` if you didn't declare any supertype. Members added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

This can be made to work as intended — but it's probably not a good approach.

The immediate issue is that the code specifies the type of `wordLengths` as `List<Any>`.  `Any` is the top type*; every type is a subtype of it, and so you can only safely access things that every type has (such as the `toString()` method).

However, you don't *need* to specify the type; you can leave that to Kotlin's type inference.  If you do, it infers the type that you've defined with the `object` keyword.  That type is anonymous — you can't write down its name — but Kotlin knows about it, and can access its fields:

```
fun main() {
    val sentence = "this is a nice sentence"

    val wordLengths = sentence.split(' ').map {
        object {
            val length = it.length
            val word = it
        }
    }

    wordLengths.forEach{ println(it.word) }
}
```

That said, it's a bit awkward and fragile.  You'd be better off defining a class for the type.  In fact, that's shorter overall:

```
fun main2() {
    val sentence = "this is a nice sentence"

    class Word(val length: Int, val word: String)

    val wordLengths = sentence.split(' ').map{ Word(it.length, it) }

    wordLengths.forEach { println(it.word) }
}
```

(In practice, you'd probably want to use the new class elsewhere, and move it outside the method.  But Kotlin lets you define local classes if you need to.)

———

(* Actually, the top type is nullable Any: `Any?`.  But I'm ignoring nullability as it's not relevant to this.)